# AlpacaJS: Observable referencing fields in a dynamic table row

Tags: javascript, alpacajs

I have a table element where people can add rows to add data. Two of the fields are mutually exclusive: if you enter a value in one, the other should be disabled, and vice versa. My understanding is I need to do this in the `postRender` callback using observables, but I can't seem to find the right path or string of IDs. And logically it doesn't make much sense how it would work. The table starts out empty.

So is there a callback to the "Add Row" button or something where I need to add this logic? Any guidance would be appreciated.

Schema:

```
    var schema = {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "cbnum": {
                "type": "string",
                "required": true,
                "minLength": 5,
                "maxLength": 5
            },
            "projects": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "name": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "title": "Project name (required)",
                            "required": true
                        },
                        "tags": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "title": "Tags"
                        },
                        "hours": {
                            "type": "number",
                            "title": "Hours"
                        },
                        "percent": {
                            "type": "number",
                            "title": "Percent"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

The following code does not work (again, not unsurprisingly when you think about it, but I don't know what else to try):

```js
    var postRenderCallback = function(control) {
        var hours = control.childrenByPropertyId["projects"].childrenByPropertyId["hours"];
        var percent = control.childrenByPropertyId["projects"].childrenByPropertyId["percent"];
        hours.on("change", function() {
            if (this.getValue().length > 0) {
                percent.setValue("");
                percent.options.disabled = true;
            } else {
                percent.options.disabled = false;
            }
        });
        percent.on("change", function() {
            if (this.getValue().length > 0) {
                hours.setValue("");
                hours.options.disabled = true;
            } else {
                hours.options.disabled = false;
            }
        });
    };
```

## Update

The following `postRenderCallback` fixed the persistent disabling problem:

```js
    var postRenderCallback = function(control) {
        var table = control.childrenByPropertyId["projects"];
        table.on("add", function() {
            var lastrow = this.children[this.children.length-1];
            var hours = lastrow.childrenByPropertyId["hours"];
            var percent = lastrow.childrenByPropertyId["percent"];
            hours.options.disabled = false;
            percent.options.disabled = false;
            hours.refresh();
            percent.refresh();
        });
    };
```

But then I ran into a couple other problems that just made this whole solution problematic (the big one being that I cannot find a way to just set a number field to blank or `undefined`; it keeps showing up as `NaN`). So I went with the following solution, which is sufficient. Here's the relevant snippet of the `options` object:

```
            "projects": {
                "type": "table",
                "actionbarStyle": "bottom",
                "items": {
                    "fields": {
                        "tags": {
                            "type": "tag"
                        },
                        "hours": {
                            "allowOptionalEmpty": true,
                            "validator": function (callback) {
                                var that = this.parent.childrenByPropertyId["percent"];
                                var thisValue = this.getValue();
                                var thatValue = that.getValue();
                                if ( (typeof thisValue !== "undefined" && !isNaN(thisValue)) && (typeof thatValue !== "undefined" && !isNaN(thatValue)) ) {
                                    callback({
                                        "status": false,
                                        "message": "You can only enter a number into one of the fields, if any. You may not have numbers in both."
                                    });
                                } else {
                                    callback({
                                        "status": true
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "percent": {
                            "allowOptionalEmpty": true,
                            "validator": function (callback) {
                                var that = this.parent.childrenByPropertyId["hours"];
                                var thisValue = this.getValue();
                                var thatValue = that.getValue();
                                if ( (typeof thisValue !== "undefined" && !isNaN(thisValue)) && (typeof thatValue !== "undefined" && !isNaN(thatValue)) ) {
                                    callback({
                                        "status": false,
                                        "message": "You can only enter a number into one of the fields, if any. You may not have numbers in both."
                                    });
                                } else {
                                    callback({
                                        "status": true
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Still not a perfect UX solution (I can't seem to make one field's validator execute another field's validator; I tried `this.parent.validate(true)`), but it's functional enough for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your schema is correct, and what you were thinking about is correct too using the `postRender` always helps but in this case not too much because you have like nested fields/objects ( array > items > item 1 > hours ) this is why your code didn't work because you cannot assign change function to all hours of all created items! plus you're using `getValue().length` on a number ( see your schema config ) and this will never work you should either use `toString` or is `isNaN` on `number` fields.

So to achieve what you're looking for you should create an `options config` and assign it to alpaca options field. And in this config you should use the `change event` on percent and hours fields and put the same code you did already on postRender for each one of them.

Here's an example:

```
"hours": {
   "events": {
       "change": function() {
            var percent = this.parent.childrenByPropertyId["percent"];
            var hoursValue = this.getValue();
            if (typeof hoursValue != 'undefined' && !isNaN(hoursValue)) {
              percent.options.disabled = true;
            } else {
              percent.options.disabled = false;
            }
            percent.refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

In `postRender` you have already a global control variable which you can use to get a field control object, but here we're on a child control so we can do it using the parent control like the following:

```
var percent = this.parent.childrenByPropertyId["percent"];
```

After you set whatever options to your hours or percent field you should call `refresh()` function to tell alpaca that you updated some config and to re-render the field for us using that updated config.

```
percent.refresh();
```

Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vert3x/m7Lg2b69/) for this solution.

And to respond to your question about the "Add Row" button, yes there is a callback for that, but I don't think it will helps you, I tried though, with the array type field you have 2 different add buttons so for me it's not a good solution because you should implement code for both buttons! the first one when you have 0 items (the toolbar button) and the second when you start adding items (the action button).

Comment: Thank you so much, Vert3x! I just didn't think about trying `this.parent` inside the event. Revelatory! I appreciate the help.

Comment: The only problem now is that when I add a new row, it remembers the disabled/enabled settings from the previous row. Now to track that down :) I assume it has something to do with the `add` event on the table itself.

Comment: Oh! ok I see, there's two other kinda complex solutions for your case, you should create custom templates and deal with handlebars...which I'm not fond of, or you create custom fields, for me the latter will be easier than dealing with handelbars, I'll do some tests and post you another solution, is that ok?

Comment: After your update on postRenderCallback have you tried to add items using not only the last rendred actionbar? have you tried to add items using like again the first actionbar? I think your postRenderCallback code will not be functional in some cases.

Comment: For the items validation there's a more clean way, can you post another question for this please, because it will be irrelevant to this question? And for disabling the fields I have a solution for you, tell me if you want another solution I'll post it for you.

Comment: Thanks so much, @vert3x. I'm sorry, I got distracted from this particular project, and I'm not getting notifications of new comments. The updated code works sufficiently well, but isn't great ux because of when validation happens. Not sure if this project is going to move forward anyway, but I'll post a follow-up question if it does. I really appreciate your time and assistance!